# Getting null result when applying not in SQL operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have two tables: opcsourcetags and real_raw_ponts.

There is a foreign key of opcsourcetags in real_raw_points table. I want to get the rows from opcsourcetags against which there is not ID in real_raw_ponits but I am getting the null result. Here is my query:

```
select * 
from OPC_SourceTags opc 
where opc.Source_Tag_Id not in (
   select rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk 
   from Real_Raw_Points rt
)
```

Comment: `where opc.Source_Tag_Id not in (
   select rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk 
   from Real_Raw_Points rt where rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk  IS NOT NULL
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below-updated query - Just added where condition in your subquery `where rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk is not null`**

*Note: If there is a null value in this column `rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk` the whole result will be null. if there is no null value then your query will also work fine hence you must apply is not null on rt.Source_Tag_Id_fk column in your subquery*

```
select * 
from OPC_SourceTags opc 
where opc.Source_Tag_Id not in (
   select rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk 
   from Real_Raw_Points rt where rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk is not null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following

```
SELECT opc.* FROM OPC_SourceTags opc
LEFT JOIN Real_Raw_Points rt ON (rt.Source_Tag_Id = opc.Source_Tag_Id)
WHERE rt.Source_Tag_Id is null;
```

Comment: Can you post the result set? This example limits the results to only OPC_SourceTags, otherwise you will get also Real_Raw_Points columns as well, which are always null.

Answer (score 1):

This is because IN/NOT IN uses 3-valued logic. In this case you've used NOT IN, ie NOT TRUE. SQL Server when checking the list of values you supply will evaluate NULL as UNKNOWN, therefore it is unknown whether the source tag id appears in the set.

IN will discard rows it cannot say with certainty are TRUE, whereas NOT IN will return UNKNOWN ie NULL for the entire set, as it cannot say with certainty that the value among the list of values you provided.

I would recommend reading more about 3-valued logic, as it's not a simple thing to explain. You can either use Mukesh's method, but this will not return rows where Source_Tag_Id_Fk is NULL in the Source_Tag_Id_Fk table. Best practice is to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN. NOT EXISTS uses two-valued logic.

```
select * 
from OPC_SourceTags opc 
where not exists (
   select rt.Source_Tag_Id_Fk 
   from Real_Raw_Points rt 
   where opc.Source_Tag_Id = rt.Source_Tag_id_Fk
)
```

Comment: Although later than the other answers, this explains the issue and provides what I think is the best alternative.